# How can I get games, like, scp to work?

Tags: unity, ssh, games

I have recently downloaded Linux, as well as unity, to my Chromebook. To test the waters of the software, I downloaded a couple games off of GameJolt, as well as SCP-Containment Breach. I can see the games in my download files, but when I try to launch them, it will not launch, no matter what program I use. (I have only tried the launchers that came with the computer). If you could reach me as soon as possible with an answer or a suggestion, I would much appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Try WINE. It's a good solution.

Comment: Do you mean alcohol?

Comment: He means [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). The games you are looking at have been developed for Windows and will not run on Linux directly. `Wine` is  compatibility layer that attempts to allow Windows apps to run under Linux. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a gamer, but I would check out the games in the software center or 'steam' to play on linux first. They are made to play on linux.  Some Windows games can be played, but you do need more work to use them.